# How can I create a graph system based on the score of my simple leaders.xml file?

Tags: php, xml, dom, graph, simplexml

I have this xml file called leaders.xml as below. When the "student" end with my test the score it is shown to him and saved into that file. What I do is to show the students in a top 10 order but I need to create something also like a graph. The graph should contain the name of the student and the score. I don't mind if it is a bar graph or something simpler. All the questions are 10.

What do you suggest me to do? All of your examples/code/scripts are highly appreciated. Thank you

```
<users>
  <user>
    <name>Bobby</name>
    <score>5</score>
  </user>
  <user>
    <name>Billy</name>
    <score>1</score>
  </user>
</users>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use google chart api to display charts. You just need to give paramiters in the url and use that url in image source. [Refer this](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)